# retrieving one record form firebase database. Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

Hi I'm doing an application in Ionic Creator and I would like to retrieve one record from database that has given email address (userId)  .
this is my code:

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseArray, $ionicUser, $state, $ionicAuth) {

$scope.userData = $ionicUser.details;

$scope.data = {
    'points': ''
}

$scope.logout = function(){
    $ionicAuth.logout();
    $state.go('tabsController.login');
};

var userId = $ionicUser.details.email;

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/users/' + userId);

$scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);
}
```

but if my code is like that it works fine but display all the data from database:

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseArray, $ionicUser, $state, $ionicAuth) {

$scope.userData = $ionicUser.details;

$scope.data = {
    'points': ''
}

$scope.logout = function(){
    $ionicAuth.logout();
    $state.go('tabsController.login');
};

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child( "users");
  // create a synchronized array
 $scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);

}
```

Any help would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

inject $firebaseObject into the controller and then do

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/users/');

$scope.user = $firebaseObject(ref.child(userId));
```

Comment: thanks for your help but still app doesn't load properly: the browser gives me this error. Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "bartek@gmail.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"     when i changed the userID to var userId = $ionicUser.details.namel; there is no error but it still doesnt display the content.